# What is the probability that the first number chosen is greater than the sum of the next three numbers chosen?

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution

> Let $ E_i\sim \mathcal N(20,3), i \in \{1,2,3,4\}.$
> What is the chance that $E_1$ is greater than $E_2+E_3+E_4? $

I started by $\mathbb P(E_1>(E_2+E_3+E_4))=\mathbb P(E_1-E_2-E_3-E_4>0).$

What steps should I take next?

Comment: What’s the distribution of $E_1-E_2-E_3-E_4?$

Comment: @Dave I am not sure...

Comment: Then what’s the distribution of the difference between normal random variables?

Comment: I dont quite understand, because the difference would be 0? @Dave

Comment: If you randomly draw two observations from $N(20,3)$, their difference is not assured to be zero. Their difference has some distribution that I suspect you’ve studied in your course.